# Chart.js - Toggle visibility of charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I really need help for this thing i'm working on.
Basically I have 4 charts rendered by chartjs. I've made 4 buttons, that simply show or hide the desired DIV. I'm pretty sure it's works on jQuery side, but I'm not so skilled to understand what's happening here on Chart.js side.

This is a demo https://jsfiddle.net/ttum6ppu/

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

   <p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs stanza_button" id="stanza" style="display:none;">Per stanza</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs stanza_selected" id="stanza"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Per stanza</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs settimanale_button" id="settimanale">Andamento settimanale</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs settimanale_selected" id="settimanale" style="display:none;"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Andamento settimanale</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs mensile_button" id="mensile">Andamento mensile</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs mensile_selected" id="mensile" style="display:none;"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Andamento mensile</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs annuo_button" id="annuo">Andamento annuo</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs annuo_selected" id="annuo" style="display:none;"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Andamento annuo</button>
   </p> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#stanza").click(function(){
        $(".stanza, .stanza_selected, .settimanale_button, .mensile_button, .annuo_button").show();
    $(".settimanale, .mensile, .annuo, .stanza_button, .settimanale_selected, .mensile_selected, .annuo_selected").hide();
    });

   $("#settimanale").click(function(){
        $(".settimanale, .settimanale_selected, .stanza_button, .mensile_button, .annuo_button").show();
    $(".stanza, .mensile, .annuo, .stanza_selected, .settimanale_button, .mensile_selected, .annuo_selected").hide();
    });

   $("#mensile").click(function(){
        $(".mensile, .mensile_selected, .stanza_button, .settimanale_button, .annuo_button").show();
    $(".stanza, .settimanale, .annuo, .stanza_selected, .settimanale_selected, .mensile_button, .annuo_selected").hide();
    });

   $("#annuo").click(function(){
        $(".annuo, .annuo_selected, .stanza_button, .settimanale_button, .mensile_button").show();
    $(".stanza, .settimanale, .mensile, .stanza_selected, .settimanale_selected, .mensile_selected, .annuo_button").hide();  
    });
});
</script>
  <div style="width: 50%">
     <div style="height:70%;" class="stanza">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="100px;"></canvas>
   </div>
   <div style="height:70%; display: none;" class="settimanale">
    <canvas id="canvas2" height="100px;"></canvas>
   </div>
   <div style="height:70%; display: none;" class="mensile">
    <canvas id="canvas3" height="100px;"></canvas>
   </div>
   <div style="height:70%; display: none;" class="annuo">
    <canvas id="canvas4" height="100px;"></canvas>
   </div>
  </div>


 <script>
 var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};

 var barChartData = {
  labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
  datasets : [
   {
    fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
    highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
    highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
   },
   {
    fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
    strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
    highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
    highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
   }
  ]

 }
 window.onload = function(){
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
   responsive : true
  });

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
  window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
   responsive : true
  });
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas3").getContext("2d");
  window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
   responsive : true
  });

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas4").getContext("2d");
  window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
   responsive : true
  });
 }

 </script>
 </body>
```

The first chart is displayed correctly, but when You press the second button it shows nothing.
Thank You in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my view a better solution is to modify the DOM to replace the canvas element, so you can redraw it with your new data :

```
var canvas_html = '<canvas id="canvas" height="100px;"></canvas>';
var drawChart = function(data) {
    // reinit canvas
    $('#canvas_container').html(canvas_html);

    // redraw chart
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, {
            responsive : true
    }); 
};
```

I have made an [update](https://jsfiddle.net/ttum6ppu/4/) of your fiddle so you can see the result.

Comment: I use `display: none` on the canvas and just init the chart once

Answer (score 1):

This is fiddly, think it's because your using Chart.js which creates the charts using iframes which are never fun to work with. Without forcing a page reload I dont think you're going to be able to do it. The canvas is being drawn at 0px height and width on the hidden charts so just changing their parents divs display using jQuery to block isn't going to cut the mustard.

[I've updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ttum6ppu/2/) so that clicking on each button shows each chart separately but the only thing I couldnt fix was hiding the last three charts on page load. Hopefully this is something that you can work with.

I've removed `display: none` from the charts

Comment: Already tried your solution but You Know....it's not good looking ...i'm gonna try to ask on GitHub's page of this plugin. Thank You

Comment: np, I've tried doing something similar with Highcharts and remember it being really tricky, maybe you could just hide the other charts using absolute positioning, z-index and a large left % like left: 1000%. Just create a class called hidden with all those styles attached and add it to the three charts you want to hide, remove it from each when you want to show them

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and solved it by looking at visibility of container div, if div is visible render chart otherwise do nothing. so on switch tab call function to render chart, by that time div should be visible.  here is sample code,

```
if ($(".canvas-holder2").is(":visible")) {

    window['myDoughnut'] = new Chart($("#chart-area")[0]
            .getContext("2d"))
            .Doughnut(data, {

                responsive: true,
                animateScale: true
            });

                window['myDoughnut'].update();
}
```